# Positioning beamer navigation symbols under the footline

Tags: beamer, header-footer, positioning

Currently my beamer configuration is something like this

```tex
\documentclass[
    xcolor,
    aspectratio=1610,
    18pt,
    hyperref={implicit=true}]{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Beamer

\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{bg=teal,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{palette secondary}{bg=violet,fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{palette tertiary}{bg=brown,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{palette quaternary}{bg=lime,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{bg=teal,fg=white}

%\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}{terciary}
    \vskip6pt\hfill \tiny {} \hskip10pt \footnotesize \insertframenumber \hskip10pt \vspace{8pt}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    content...
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

which produces
[image]

The navigation symbols looks awful this way, but i think it looks really great switching positions

[image]

How can I place the navigation symbols under the footline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the navigation symbols to the footline:

```
\documentclass[
    xcolor,
    aspectratio=1610,
    18pt,
    hyperref={implicit=true}]{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Beamer

\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{bg=teal,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{palette secondary}{bg=violet,fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{palette tertiary}{bg=brown,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{palette quaternary}{bg=lime,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{bg=teal,fg=white}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

%\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}{terciary}
    \vskip6pt\hfill \tiny {} \hskip10pt \footnotesize \insertframenumber \hskip10pt \vspace{8pt}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    
    \hfill\usebeamercolor[fg]{navigation symbols}\usebeamerfont{navigtaion symbols}\hbox{%
        \hbox{\insertslidenavigationsymbol}
        \hbox{\insertframenavigationsymbol}
        \hbox{\insertsubsectionnavigationsymbol}
        \hbox{\insertsectionnavigationsymbol}
        \hbox{\insertdocnavigationsymbol}
        \hbox{\insertbackfindforwardnavigationsymbol}%
    }\quad\mbox{}%
}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]